# Modularised Document Construction

Tags: vba, excel, modules

The goal: A set of configurable options, combined with a standardised data source, to produce a standardised Report.

This question: One module of said document, with accompanying code.

**Input:** (Dropdown selection): An **Attitude To Risk (ATR)** Value. 1 to 5.

**Business Logic:** Select from pre-configured descriptions and hardcoded text sections. Insert relevant name into introduction text. Format as appropriate.

**Output:** An attitude to risk description and overview. Printable.

---

**Input:**
[image]

**Hardcoded Text:**
[image]

**Pre-Configured Descriptions:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

---

Considering this document is likely to span to ~30 sections or more, is my current approach sufficiently modularised and self-contained?

Have I chosen a bad way to go about this? (I considered building it in Word, but Word is, well, messy).

How's my naming?
Is it okay to hard-code Named Ranges like that?
How easy is it to follow my code?
Any other feedback is, of course, welcomed.

Code:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BtnMakeSelections_OnClick()

    DisableApplicationSettings


    FillAtrSheet


    ResetApplicationSettings

End Sub

Public Sub FormatAsPlainText(ByRef formatRange As Range)

    formatRange.Font.Size = 12
    formatRange.Font.Bold = False
    formatRange.Font.ColorIndex = 0

End Sub

Public Function GetAtrNum() As Long

    Dim atrRange As Range
    Set atrRange = wsInputs.Range("ATR_Selection")

    Dim atrNum As Long
    atrNum = CLng(atrRange.value)

    GetAtrNum = atrNum

End Function

Public Sub CopyPasteCell(ByRef copyCell As Range, ByRef pasteCell As Range, Optional ByVal pasteRowHeights As Boolean = False)

    copyCell.Copy
    pasteCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    If pasteRowHeights Then
        Dim sourceRowHeight As Long
        sourceRowHeight = copyCell.rowHeight
        pasteCell.rowHeight = sourceRowHeight
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub FindAndFormatAsHeading(ByRef targetCell As Range, ByVal targetString As String)

    If HasCharacters(targetCell) Then
        Dim targetCharacters As Characters
        Set targetCharacters = GetCharacters(targetCell, targetString)

        FormatAsHeading targetCharacters
    End If

End Sub

Public Function GetCharacters(ByRef targetCell As Range, ByVal targetString As String) As Characters

    Dim targetCharacters As Characters

    If HasCharacters(targetCell) Then
        Dim targetRange As Range
        If targetCell.MergeCells Then
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = targetCell.Worksheet
''            ws.Activate
            Set targetRange = ws.Cells(targetCell.row, targetCell.Column)
        Else
            Set targetRange = targetCell
        End If

        Dim cellText As String
        cellText = targetRange.text

        Dim ixString As Long
        ixString = InStr(1, cellText, targetString)

        Set targetCharacters = targetRange.Characters(ixString, Len(targetString))
    Else
        Set targetCharacters = Nothing
    End If

    Set GetCharacters = targetCharacters

End Function

Public Sub FormatAsHeading(ByRef targetCharacters As Characters)

    targetCharacters.Font.Bold = True
    targetCharacters.Font.Color = ColorValueFromRgb(0, 119, 139)

End Sub
```

---

### Module: `Atr_Sheets`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillAtrSheet()
    '/ Copy/Paste relevant cell from ATR selection Sheet
    '/ Insert name into description, format name (bold, heading colour)

    Dim atrNum As Long
    atrNum = GetAtrNum

    If atrNum = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select an ATR Number"
        RestoreApplicationSettings
        End
    End If

    PasteAtrDescription atrNum

    ModifyAtrIntroText atrNum

End Sub

Public Function GetAtrNum() As Long

    Dim atrRange As Range
    Set atrRange = wsInputs.Range("ATR_Selection")

    Dim atrNum As Long
    atrNum = CLng(atrRange.value)

    GetAtrNum = atrNum

End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub PasteAtrDescription(ByVal atrNum As Long)

    Dim copyRange As Range
    Set copyRange = wsAtrCopyRanges.Range(AtrRangeNameFromAtr(atrNum))

    Dim pasteRange As Range
    Set pasteRange = wsAtr.Range("ATR_Paste_Range")

    CopyPasteCell copyRange, pasteRange, pasteRowHeights:=True

End Sub

Public Function AtrRangeNameFromAtr(ByVal atrNum As Long) As String

    Dim rangeName As String
    Dim prefixString As String, suffixString As String
    prefixString = "ATR_"
    suffixString = "_Selection"

    rangeName = prefixString & atrNum & suffixString

    AtrRangeNameFromAtr = rangeName

End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub ModifyAtrIntroText(ByVal atrNum As Long)
    '/ Insert ATR Name into cell text. Format cell as plain text. Colour/bold ATR Name.

    Dim atrName As String
    atrName = AtrNameFromAtrNum(atrNum)

    Dim atrIntroText As String
    atrIntroText = AtrIntroTextFromAtrNum(atrNum)

    Dim atrIntroCell As Range
    Set atrIntroCell = wsAtr.Range("ATR_Intro_Cell")

    atrIntroCell.value = atrIntroText
    FormatAsPlainText atrIntroCell

    FindAndFormatAsHeading atrIntroCell, atrName

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function AtrIntroTextFromAtrNum(ByVal atrNum As Long) As String

    Dim atrPrefixText As String, atrSuffixText As String

    atrPrefixText = HardcodedText.item("ATR_Intro_Prefix")
    atrSuffixText = HardcodedText.item("ATR_Intro_Suffix")

    Dim atrName As String
    atrName = AtrNameFromAtrNum(atrNum, prependPrefix:=True)

    Dim atrIntroText As String
    atrIntroText = atrPrefixText & atrName & atrSuffixText

    AtrIntroTextFromAtrNum = atrIntroText

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function AtrNameFromAtrNum(ByVal atrNum As Long, Optional ByVal prependPrefix As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim atrName As String

    Select Case atrNum

        Case 1
        atrName = "Cautious"

        Case 2
        atrName = "Cautious To Moderate"

        Case 3
        atrName = "Moderate"

        Case 4
        atrName = "Moderate To Adventurous"

        Case 5
        atrName = "Adventurous"

    End Select

    If prependPrefix Then
        Dim startsWithVowel As Boolean
        startsWithVowel = IsVowel(Left(atrName, 1))

        Dim prefix As String
        If startsWithVowel Then prefix = "an" Else prefix = "a"

        atrName = prefix & " " & atrName
    End If

    AtrNameFromAtrNum = atrName

End Function
```

---

Comment: Just curious - in `FillAtrSheet` why did  you choose to use `End` instead of an `Exit` - If you exit you'd hit `resetapplicationsettings` and wouldn't need to call `restoreapplicationsettings` - is there a significant difference between the two?

Comment: Not particularly, reset is just there whilst I'm building it. End is because, in the bigger picture, if any information is missing then it needs to be entered before the document can be generated, so there's no point in running the rest of the code.

Comment: Where does this "output" end up? Does it stay in the XLS, or is it pasted into an email, saved as a PDF or sent to a physical printer? Also, Row 7 in your output example seems taller than necessary. Are you concerned about the consistency of spacing between paragraphs?

Comment: It remains in Excel for final editing/tweaking then gets exported to PDF. Line 7 is not a problem. Lines that need to be appropriately spaced will be, either by default or through the 'CopyPaste' function.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I wanted to post the following as a comment. But it is too much text for a comment and therefore I am posting it **not** as an answer but merely "for your consideration":

I (personally) hate `named ranges`. Just like mentioned in your question that "Word is kind of messy" I have the same experience with named ranges. People are copying things into your workbook and named ranges get changed or end up broken. Some people are not aware that they are not supposed to touch the named ranges and ... well, still they do.

I do know that - at some point - you have to code a reference and all of them can get broken (especially in Excel where there is almost no security). So the following is probably more of a "taste" thing and can be well debated:

I (personally again) prefer a `very hidden` Ref sheet where I duplicate (linked cells) all important data and then take everything for my code from that sheet instead. The essential advantage of this solution over named ranges is that (1) you have all important data in one place and that (2) broken links can be easily fixed. Furthermore, you have (3) an entire sheet. That allows you for more information and possible "meta data" or background information (when compared to only having the name of a named range). You may even color code your Ref sheet to make it easier to navigate (for yourself and others).

Since Office 2007+ the compression on Excel files is pretty good and the increase in file size is negligible. Other than that linked cells behave pretty similar to named ranges and (when moved within the file) do not break but get automatically "fixed" to the new location.

Another approach is described here (which I still prefer over named ranges): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800416/working-with-changing-named-ranges-excel-vba/36800944#36800944

<sub>Disclaimer: as I said. These are merely my personal preferences. Still, I can say that this works pretty well (for years) in a rather large corporation environment.</sub>

Comment: Why do you consider this to not be an answer?

Comment: This answer has been [mentioned on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6747/9357).